# python filter 2d array by a chunk of data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [20,  0,  5,  1],
    [20,  0,  5,  1],
    [20,  0,  5,  0],
    [20,  1,  5,  0],
    [20,  1,  5,  0],
    [20,  2,  5,  1],
    [20,  3,  5,  0],
    [20,  3,  5,  0],
    [20,  3,  5,  1],
    [20,  4,  5,  0],
    [20,  4,  5,  0],
    [20,  4,  5,  0]
])
```

I have the following 2d array. lets called the fields `a, b, c, d` in the above order where column `b` is like `id`. I wish to delete all cells that doesnt have atlist 1 appearance of the number "1" in column `d` for all cells with the same number in column `b` (same id) so after filtering i will have the following results:

```
[[20  0  5  1]
 [20  0  5  1]
 [20  0  5  0]
 [20  2  5  1]
 [20  3  5  0]
 [20  3  5  0]
 [20  3  5  1]]
```

all rows with `b = 1` and `b = 4` have been deleted from the data

to sum up because I see answers that doesnt fit. we look at chunks of data by the `b` column. if a complete chunk of data doesnt have even one appearance of the number "1" in column `d` we delete all the rows of that `b` item. in the following example we can see a chunk of data with `b = 1` and `b = 4` ("id" = 1 and "id" = 4) that have 0 appearances of the number "1" in column `d`. thats why it gets deleted from the data

Comment: Is this a list of lists, or a numpy array? Tried anything yet?

Comment: this works as numpy array. it was generated from this command: result = np.loadtxt("name.csv", delimiter = ",").astype(int). a line in the file look like this: 5.0000,20090.0000,0.1854,1.0000

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code. Comments aren't meant for code

Comment: Done. Is the question clearer?

Comment: I meant add the numpy code, but sure

Comment: Is column b guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: And is `b` guaranteed to be sequential integers?

Comment: yes it is sorted and is easily sorted if not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Generic approach :** Here's an approach using [`np.unique`](https://numeric.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to solve for a generic case -

```
unq,tags = np.unique(data[:,1],return_inverse=1)
goodIDs = np.flatnonzero(np.bincount(tags,data[:,3]==1)>=1)
out = data[np.in1d(tags,goodIDs)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: data
Out[15]: 
array([[20, 10,  5,  1],
       [20, 73,  5,  0],
       [20, 73,  5,  1],
       [20, 31,  5,  0],
       [20, 10,  5,  1],
       [20, 10,  5,  0],
       [20, 42,  5,  1],
       [20, 54,  5,  0],
       [20, 73,  5,  0],
       [20, 54,  5,  0],
       [20, 54,  5,  0],
       [20, 31,  5,  0]])

In [16]: out
Out[16]: 
array([[20, 10,  5,  1],
       [20, 73,  5,  0],
       [20, 73,  5,  1],
       [20, 10,  5,  1],
       [20, 10,  5,  0],
       [20, 42,  5,  1],
       [20, 73,  5,  0]])
```

**Specific case approach :**  If the second column data is always sorted and have sequential numbers starting from `0`, we can use a simplified version, like so -

```
goodIDs = np.flatnonzero(np.bincount(data[:,1],data[:,3]==1)>=1)
out = data[np.in1d(data[:,1],goodIDs)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: data
Out[44]: 
array([[20,  0,  5,  1],
       [20,  0,  5,  1],
       [20,  0,  5,  0],
       [20,  1,  5,  0],
       [20,  1,  5,  0],
       [20,  2,  5,  1],
       [20,  3,  5,  0],
       [20,  3,  5,  0],
       [20,  3,  5,  1],
       [20,  4,  5,  0],
       [20,  4,  5,  0],
       [20,  4,  5,  0]])

In [45]: out
Out[45]: 
array([[20,  0,  5,  1],
       [20,  0,  5,  1],
       [20,  0,  5,  0],
       [20,  2,  5,  1],
       [20,  3,  5,  0],
       [20,  3,  5,  0],
       [20,  3,  5,  1]])
```

Also, if `data[:,3]` always have ones and zeros, we can just use `data[:,3]` in place of `data[:,3]==1` in the above listed codes.

---

**Benchmarking**

Let's benchmark the vectorized approaches on the specific case for a larger array -

```
In [69]: def logical_or_based(data): #@ Eric's soln
    ...:     b_vals = data[:,1]
    ...:     d_vals = data[:,3]
    ...:     is_ok = np.zeros(np.max(b_vals) + 1, dtype=np.bool_)
    ...:     np.logical_or.at(is_ok, b_vals, d_vals)
    ...:     return is_ok[b_vals]
    ...: 
    ...: def in1d_based(data):
    ...:     goodIDs = np.flatnonzero(np.bincount(data[:,1],data[:,3])!=0)
    ...:     out = np.in1d(data[:,1],goodIDs)
    ...:     return out
    ...: 

In [70]: # Setup input
    ...: data = np.random.randint(0,100,(10000,4))
    ...: data[:,1] = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,100,(10000)))
    ...: data[:,3] = np.random.randint(0,2,(10000))
    ...: 

In [71]: %timeit logical_or_based(data) #@ Eric's soln
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit in1d_based(data)
1000 loops, best of 3: 528 µs per loop
```

Comment: In theory this should be a little slower than my answer, right? Since this is `O(max(b)*N)`, and I think mine is `O(N)`? Or am I misunderstanding the complexity of `np.in1d`?

Comment: @Eric Well `np.in1d` isn't doing exactly the same task as `np.logical_or.at`, so I can't comment on the performance. Of course, after indexing with `is_ok[b_vals]` it's getting to the same boolean array, so it seems alongwith with `np.logical_or.at`, we need indexing too. Added some runtime test to time the approaches themselves if you were looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [[20,0,5,1],
    [20,0,5,1],
    [20,0,5,0],
    [20,1,5,0],
    [20,1,5,0],
    [20,2,5,1],
    [20,3,5,0],
    [20,3,5,0],
    [20,3,5,1],
    [20,4,5,0],
    [20,4,5,0],
    [20,4,5,0]]

all_ids = np.array(my_list)[:,1]
unique_ids = np.unique(all_ids)
indices = [np.where(all_ids==ui)[0][0] for ui in unique_ids ]

final = []
for id in unique_ids:
    try:
        tmp_group = my_list[indices[id]:indices[id+1]]
    except:
        tmp_group = my_list[indices[id]:]
    if 1 in np.array(tmp_group)[:,3]:
        final.extend(tmp_group)

print np.array(final)
```

result:

```
[[20  0  5  1]
 [20  0  5  1]
 [20  0  5  0]
 [20  2  5  1]
 [20  3  5  0]
 [20  3  5  0]
 [20  3  5  1]]
```

Comment: I dont want to specificly delete the rows where my_list[1] == 1. I want to delete those rows only if all the rows where my_list[1] = i are also 0 in my_list[3]

Comment: @EranMoshe I see, give me a second I'm fixing it

Comment: i built a different example u can check it now

Comment: @EranMoshe check it now

Comment: thats nice.. but the run-time is insane.. tmp_group = [item for item in my_list if item[1]==id] is just a waist of runtime, the data is sorted by the "b" column i need a solution that iterates on the data a constant number of times

Comment: @EranMoshe check this new version it should be much faster

Answer (score 1):

This gets rid of all rows with 1 in the second position:

```
[sublist for sublist in list_ if sublist[1] != 1]
```

This get's rid of all rows with 1 in the second position unless the fourth position is also 1:

```
[sublist for sublist in list_ if not (sublist[1] == 1 and sublist[3] != 1) ]
```

Comment: The actual requirement is to get rid of any rows for which the value in the second column never appears matched with a 1 in the last column in any of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the following:

- `b >= 0`
- `b` is an integer
- `b` is fairly dense, ie `max(b) ~= len(unique(b))`

Here's a solution using [`np.ufunc.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
# unpack for clarity - this costs nothing in numpy
b_vals = data[:,1]
d_vals = data[:,3]

# build an array indexed by b values
is_ok = np.zeros(np.max(b_vals) + 1, dtype=np.bool_)
np.logical_or.at(is_ok, b_vals, d_vals)
# is_ok == array([ True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

# take the rows which have a b value that was deemed OK
result = data[is_ok[b_vals]]
```

---

`np.logical_or.at(is_ok, b_vals, d_vals)` is a more efficient version of:

```
for idx, val in zip(b_vals, d_vals):
    is_ok[idx] = np.logical_or(is_ok[idx], val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested since in a hurry, but this should work:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
g = npi.group_by(data[:, 1])
ids, valid = g.any(data[:, 3])
result = data[valid[g.inverse]]
```